# Trouble printing from a for loop

Tags: python, json, pandas, for-loop

Still pretty new to python... Trying to pull data from an API and print the output of each string in my list to json. Issue is, the loop runs every string in my list fine, but only prints the last string in the list (Retail).

Here is the code:

```
today = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).isoformat() + "T05:00:00"
start = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).isoformat() + "T05:00:00"
myList = ['Financials', 'Industry', 'Health Wellbeing', 'Manufacturing', 'Retail']


for list in myList:
    filtered = queries.get_mentions(name = list,
                                startDate = start,
                                endDate = today,
                                )
df = pd.DataFrame(filtered, columns=['account', 'addedtime',    'author',   'id',   'impact',   'snippet'])
Export_tojson = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You are overwriting the value of `filtered` on each pass. Either collect the results in a list, or use `filtered` before moving on to the next iteration.

Comment: In other words, indent the last two lines

Comment: thanks, unfortunately when I transferred the code to stack, I must of pasted it without the indents. I have the code indented in my code and it's still overwriting like @chepner explained

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are overwriting the value of `filtered` on each iteration without setting it's value in your data frame.

One way to overcome this, as @chepner mentioned in the comments would be to change `filtered` to be of type list instead

```py
for list in myList:
    filtered = []

    filtered.append(queries.get_mentions(name = list,
                                startDate = start,
                                endDate = today,
                                ))
```

Hope this helps :) if you require any further clarification or help please feel free to start a chat with me!

Comment: hey CyberStems, I really appreciate your feedback. When I tried your version I ended up with an assertion error: AssertionError: 111 columns passed, passed data had 1429 columns... Any thoughts?

Comment: can you please show me how you are passing the lists values to your dataframe?

Comment: In the list from above, you will see myList. That has all of the elements I am passing through the for loop. And in the queries.get_mention(name=list)... The name=list is where I am referencing the for loop to get every element of the list named myList. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: As for the list items to the data frame, originally I was passing the filtered output to the pd.dataframe

Comment: honestly, I'm not sure why you're getting that error. A cheeky workaround though would be concatenating all elements in the list into a string with some delimiter. Then when you want to convert it back into a list you can simply split it. If my answer isn't helpful please let me know and I can remove it.